# Second round interview for a postdoctoral position

Tags: postdocs, interview

I have applied for a postdoctoral position at a university in Ireland, and have done an interview with the professor who advertised the position. After three weeks from the interview, I sent him an email asking whether there are any updates regarding my application, and he told me I need to go through a second round interview with one faculty in the department, as it was a university requirement.

Can someone please tell me what are the questions likely to be asked during the second round interview? Knowing that during the first interview we discussed all aspects of my research and the research and teaching duties I will have to take in case I was accepted.

Edit: Would it be just to discuss the contract? Like the salary, the working hours, how many papers I am expected to publish, and how many courses to teach etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell.  Could want to talk about your research or could be general science/subject questions or could even be soft questions like work ethic or compatibility.

I would ask the person who is trying to hire you for any advice on the content.  Also push for a time (be proactive and say what your wondows are, offer to reach out if acceptible).  Sounds like the first guy is trying to hire you but a little slack on the process.  But I am reading tea leaves.

Also keep some hooks in the water and keep looking for other postings.  This opportunity might go cold.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The PI has given me the name of the faculty with whom I will conduct the interview, and I sent him an email today asking when we will have the interview, I am waiting for his reply. I did not want to be too specific or ask for too many information as I am not sure how would he feel about this. But I would be really happy if this goes smoothly and quickly, I feel like I'm just wasting time waiting.